# meson-build: wxWidgets Resource file for Windows not building

Tags: c++, wxwidgets, mingw-w64, msys2, meson-build

I'm developing an application using wxWidgets for the UI. The project can target Windows and Linux, I'm using meson/ninja to build.

Building in General works fine for both platforms, as long as I'm not using a Resource (.rc) file on Windows.

When I add the .rc-File, it fails to compile. I use MSYS2/mingw_w64 on Windows as the toolchain.

For testing purposes, I've created a little sample for testing and reproducing.

This sample involves the following files:

- cpp-file, with some wxWidgets "Hello World" testcode.
- .rc-file, defining the Theme & appicon for windows.
- meson.build-file, configuration for meson
- Some Icon Files

I run the following command from within MSYS2-MINGW64 CLI in Windows:

```
meson build_win && cd build_win && ninja
```

Some files/folders are generated, but the build process fails. Output from Terminal:

```
The Meson build system
Version: 0.53.0
Source dir: //192.168.122.1/VMShare_1/Tests/meson-test
Build dir: //192.168.122.1/VMShare_1/Tests/meson-test/build_win
Build type: native build
Project name: TestWXApp
Project version: undefined
C compiler for the host machine: cc (gcc 9.2.0 "cc (Rev2, Built by MSYS2 project) 9.2.0")
C linker for the host machine: cc GNU ld.bfd 2.33.1
Host machine cpu family: x86_64
Host machine cpu: x86_64
C++ compiler for the host machine: c++ (gcc 9.2.0 "c++ (Rev2, Built by MSYS2 project) 9.2.0")
C++ linker for the host machine: c++ GNU ld.bfd 2.33.1
wx-config found: YES (sh C:\msys64\mingw64\bin/wx-config) 3.0.4
Run-time dependency WxWidgets found: YES 3.0.4
Windows resource compiler: GNU windres (GNU Binutils) 2.33.1
Build targets in project: 2

Found ninja.EXE-1.9.0 at C:\msys64\mingw64\bin/ninja.EXE
[1/3] Generating Windows resource for file '._resources_theme_win32.rc' with a custom command.
FAILED: ._resources_theme_win32.rc_theme_win32.o
"C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/windres.EXE" ".././resources/theme_win32.rc" "._resources_theme_win32.rc_theme_win32.o" "--preprocessor-arg=-MD" "--preprocessor-arg=-MQ._resources_theme_win32.rc_theme_win32.o" "--preprocessor-arg=-MF._resources_theme_win32.rc_theme_win32.o.d"
.././resources/theme_win32.rc:2:10: fatal error: wx/msw/wx.rc: No such file or directory
    2 | #include "wx/msw/wx.rc"
      |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~
compilation terminated.
C:/msys64/mingw64/bin/windres.EXE: preprocessing failed.
[2/3] Compiling C++ object TestWXApp@exe/src_wxExample.cpp.obj.
ninja: build stopped: subcommand failed.
```

That looks like I need to add the dependency wxWidgets for the resource compiler, but I don't figure out how.

meson.build:

```
project('TestWXApp', 'c')

add_languages('cpp', required : true)

src_data = []

if build_machine.system() == 'windows'
    #compile static wxWidgets on windows
    wxDep = dependency('wxwidgets',
                       version : '>=3.0.0',
                       required : true,
                       modules : ['--static', 'std', 'stc'])

    mod_rescomp = import('windows')
    src_data += mod_rescomp.compile_resources('./resources/theme_win32.rc')
else
    #build for linux
    wxDep = dependency('wxwidgets',
                       version : '>=3.0.0',
                       required : true,
                       modules : ['std', 'stc'])
endif

src_data += ['./src/wxExample.cpp']
inc_tool = include_directories('./src')

inc_res = include_directories('./resources')

executable('TestWXApp',
           sources : [src_data],
           include_directories : [inc_res],
           dependencies : wxDep)
```

I've put a tarball including the whole Project (+the generated build_win-folder) here: https://lots-of.space/s/NLqmJzjcrknKqbX

If more information is required, let me know. I hope someone can point me to the right direction.

Regards,

XXXBold

**Update, 26.01.2020**

I'm now able to build the project, however, for now it requires hardcoded paths. I've found these paths by running the wx-config within the terminal and manually copying the output:

```
wx-config --cppflags --static
```

Documentation for the resourcecompiler on meson can be found here: https://mesonbuild.com/Windows-module.html#page-description

New meson.build-file:

```
project('TestWXApp', 'c')

add_languages('cpp', required : true)

src_data = []

if build_machine.system() == 'windows'
    #compile static wxWidgets on windows
    wxDep = dependency('wxwidgets',
                       version : '>=3.0.0',
                       required : true,
                       modules : ['--static', 'std', 'stc'])

    mod_rescomp = import('windows')
    src_data += mod_rescomp.compile_resources('./resources/theme_win32.rc',
                                             args : ['-IC:/msys64/mingw64/lib/wx/include/msw-unicode-static-3.0',
                                                     '-IC:/msys64/mingw64/include/wx-3.0',
                                                     '-D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64',
                                                     '-D__WXMSW__'])

else
    #build for linux
    wxDep = dependency('wxwidgets',
                       version : '>=3.0.0',
                       required : true,
                       modules : ['std', 'stc'])
endif

src_data += ['./src/wxExample.cpp']
inc_tool = include_directories('./src')

inc_res = include_directories('./resources')

executable('TestWXApp',
           sources : [src_data],
           include_directories : [inc_res],
           dependencies : wxDep)
```

I'm sure there's a better way doing this...

Answer (score 0):

I don't know Meson, but you need to provide the path to wxWidgets include directory for the resource compiler (`rc.exe`) and not just the C++ compiler itself.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I've found out how to build it the ugly way, see edit above.

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the same problem as you have after the update 26.01.2020.

I posted a related question: [How to get the include directories from a dependency in meson build system](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60864453/how-to-get-the-include-directories-from-a-dependency-in-meson-build-system)

One workaround is to get the `cppflags` variable from `wxDep` and split it to an array and pass it to the `args` parameter of `compile_resources`. But that has the drawback of not working if any of the include paths contains a space. This is a small example:

```
project('project1', ['cpp'])
windows = import('windows')
src = ['main.cpp']

wxDep = dependency('wxwidgets')
wx_cppflags = wxDep.get_configtool_variable('cppflags')
wx_cppflags_arr = wx_cppflags.split(' ')

src += windows.compile_resources('test.rc', args: wx_cppflags_arr)

executable('testapp',
           sources : src,
           dependencies : wxDep)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is the way I do it (credit to [@dcbaker](https://github.com/dcbaker), [github.com/mesonbuild/meson#6897](https://github.com/mesonbuild/meson/issues/6897)).

Indeed, `wx-config` has a way of giving us all necessary arguments (this sample is from my MSYS2 installation):

```
$ wx-config --rescomp
windres --include-dir C:/msys64/mingw64/include/wx-3.0 --define __WIN32__ --define __GNUWIN32__ --define WX_CPU_AMD64
```

We can run that command, remove the preceding "windres" and use the remaining string as `args` to `compile_resources`.

"There is one ugly thing in here that meson arrays don't have a good way to take slices, so I've done a little hack to remove windres from the args list"

```
wx_dep = dependency('wxwidgets')
raw_wx_windres_args = wx_dep.get_variable(configtool : 'rescomp').split()
wx_windres_args = []
foreach a : raw_wx_windres_args
  if a != 'windres'
    wx_windres_args += a
  endif
endforeach

win = import('windows')
rc_file = win.compile_resources('resources/windows.rc', args : wx_windres_args)
```