# How to get the include directories from a dependency in meson build system

Tags: meson-build

In meson build system, I want to get the include directories from a dependency:

Simple example meson.build, using wxWidgets dependecy as example:

```
project('project1', ['cpp'])

wxdep = dependency('wxWidgets')

wxincludes =    # ... how to get the include directories from wxdep ?

# in this case, wxincludes will be used to compile a resource file:
windows = import('windows')
windows.compile_resources('test.rc', include_directories: [wxincludes])
```

How can I get the include directories from a dependency for use in subsequent commands?

Answer (score 0):

A bit late response, but hope it will help you anyway.

meson's `dependency` object contains following things: source and header files, libraries to link with, compiler flags and linker flags.

So, answering your question directly - you should only pass `wxdep` as a dependency to your target, and meson will handle all other things inside.